# How to make SXA Dropdown filter default value selected

Tags: sxa

I have a `Sitecore SXA` dropdown filter on the page. On page load, by default first item is getting selected (***All***). I would like to provide the default value that should be selected on page load.

For example, I would like to configure ***Deer*** option selected on page load.

I was thinking of writing JavaScript but that will be hardcoded / page specific. We might want to configure a different default selected value on different pages.

What is the easiest way to achieve this?

[image: dropdown list in SXA]